# getAllData does not include element just inserted, even after callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, nedb

So I am using NeDB as a data store for a simple little project, and I want to create a little API that inserts something new and returns the list of all items in the datastore, including the new one.

```js
async function willAddNewItem() {
    // db is NeDB Datastore
    const existing = db.getAllData();
    const sortedIds = existing
        .map(item => item.id)
        .sort((one, another) => one - another);
    const id = sortedIds.length === 0
        ? 0
        : sortedIds.slice(-1)[0] + 1;
    const newItem = { id, foo: 'bar' };

    await new Promise(resolve => db.insert(newItem, () => resolve()));

    return db.getAllData()
        .sort((one, another) =>
            new Date(one.updatedAt).getTime() - new Date(another.updatedAt).getTime()
        );
}
```

However, every time I call this function, I get the list of items I had *before* inserting the new one. On the next call, the item I added last time would be there, but not the new one. Refreshing my page (which results in calling `db.getAllData()` again to populate the initial page) shows everything it should. It’s only missing immediately after I insert it. So it would appear that the callback on `db.insert` is not actually waiting until the insertion is complete (nor is there any documentation that I can find about this).

Adding an index to `id` fixes this, and I do *want* an index on `id` so that is good, but I still want to know why this is happening/where I have to be careful about it happening in the future. For that matter, I’m a little worried that the only reason adding the index to `id` worked is because it happened to be a little faster, so it was “done” before I called `db.getAllData()` when it wasn’t before—and that this may not be consistent.

I could use something like

```js
const afterAdding = await new Promise(resolve =>
    db.insert(newItem, (_, newDoc) => resolve([...existing, newDoc]))
);
```

and return the sorted `afterAdding`, but this seems a little dubious to me (I’d really like to get exactly the db’s state rather than try to “recreate” it myself, assuming that `insert` has done exactly and only what I expected), and in any event I would like to know more about how NeDB works here.

Also, yes, I know I’m ignoring possible errors on the insert (I have checked to see if this is the cause; it is not), and I probably don’t want `.getAllData()` at all but rather some `.find` query. This is a basic test case as I get familiar with NeDB.

Comment: Have you tried checking for the presence of an error on the callback on `insert`? Could it be that it's simply not inserting the new data?

Comment: @OliverRadini No, no error, and on the next call I get the list including the first one, and then on the third call the second is there, and so on. Edited to clarify that.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing this with the code you have, when I try, the function returns all the data, including the newly added item. Are you able to provide any more detail about the implementation you have?

Comment: @OliverRadini Aside from some basic boilerplate responding to the API call, and a slightly larger object being inserted (`id`, two short strings, an empty array, and a number), this really matches what I have. As I noted in an edit, adding an index to `id` fixes the problem, and actually when I remove that index I can’t reproduce the problem anymore, either. Which makes me wonder if it wasn’t just a build snafu (I’m actually using Typescript) that caused me to still be using my original version (which did not `await` the insert) when I was trying to test the `await` version.

Comment: @OliverRadini Thanks for taking the time to try to reproduce, I really appreciate that. Unfortunately, unless I can reproduce it myself (assuming it wasn’t a build snafu—I’m using `tsc` in watch mode and `nodemon` and it’s been finicky), I doubt this question is likely to go anywhere. Even more unfortunately, I cannot think of any way to determine for sure that it was a build problem. I’m sure going back to the version without `await` will fail to work, but that doesn’t rule out some weird timing issue with the `await` version...

Comment: that's a shame; hopefully someone who has used nedb can investigate this and come up with a useful answer!